# Chave primaria composta de duas chaves estrangeiras

Tags: hibernate, jpa, java-ee, spring-mvc, spring-jpa

Boa tarde a todos!
Estou com uma duvida na estrutura de uma Entity, estou usando Hibernate+JPA. A classe se trata de uma classificação de usuários, onde uma chave primaria será o usuário (vindo da classe Usuario), e a outra é a temporada (vinda da classe temporada). Segue abaixo a estrutura da classe:

```
@Entity(name = "CLASSIFICACAO")
@Data
public class Classificacao implements Serializable
{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator="SharedPrimaryKeyGenerator")
  @GenericGenerator(name="SharedPrimaryKeyGenerator",strategy="foreign",parameters =  @Parameter(name="property", value="usuario"))
  @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
  private String classificacao;
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator="SharedPrimaryKeyGenerator")
  @GenericGenerator(name="SharedPrimaryKeyGenerator",strategy="foreign",parameters =  @Parameter(name="property", value="temporada"))
  @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
  private Long codTemporada;
  //another fields  
  @OneToOne
  @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
  private Usuario usuario;
  @ManyToOne
  @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
  private Temporada temporada;
}
```

O campo **classificacao** recebe o nome do usuario vindo da chave estrangeira **Usuario**;
Antes eu nao tinha o campo **codTemporada** como primaria, e funcionava lindo. Classificação recebia usuário e era primaria, e a temporada apenas estrangeira. Mas agora preciso que o campo **temporada** também seja primaria tornando uma classe de chaves primarias composta. Mas só estoura o erro *broken column mapping for: usuario.id of: br.com.xxxxx.model.Classificacao*.

Alguma luz do que posso fazer ?

Answer (score 0):

Achei a solução para o meu problema! Segue abaixo para quem precisar:

Classificacao.java

```
@Entity
public class Classificacao implements Serializable {

    @Id
    ClassificacaoId id;

    String name;
    // getter and setter

}
```

ClassificacaoId.java

```
@Embeddable
public class ClassificacaoId implements Serializable {

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId", referencedColumnName = "userId")
    private Usuario usuarioIo;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "tempId", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Temporada temporada;

    // getter and setter

}
```